# Login redirect_to url is pointing to a url with the port

Tags: wp-admin, redirect

I have recently installed Wordpress when I login the wp-admin is opening a url with port. Upon inspection of the redirect_to url it is the correct url for example: "www.website.com/blog/" but it opens or redirects to a url with a port added to it as in this example: "www.website.com:**8888**/blog/".

I have reviewed all the urls in my installation and it is the correct url.
I have reviewed htaccess, wp-config.php, and functions.php no sign of "www.website.com:**8888**/blog/"

Any ideas?

Comment: There's also the blog URL and site URL, which are in Settings, General in the admin dashboard or in the wp_options table in the database, if you haven't checked those too.

Comment: i have checked them as well and they have the correct URL, I have not encountered this error before. To add to this, the site is behind a reverse proxy. All other URLs are working fine except for when the link involves /wp-admin. I had to manually delete the port to be able to access the dashboard.